# mysqli_fetch_assoc not working on stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

whats wrong with my code?

```
$rs_drcus = mysqli_query($con,"CALL sp_cons_dr_cusfsp('" .$main_appkey. "')");
            while ($rw_drcus = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs_drcus)) {
                $arr_drcus[] = $rw_drcus;
            }
```

It gives me this error

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Comment: I guess `mysqli_query` returns `false` so the query failed, that's why you can't use it with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Check PHP/MySQL errors from your query. You can try this before using mysqli `error_reporting(-1);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & ~MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);`

Comment: sir for example this is the parameter i am using does this one has an effect? `02/09/2018 10:10:00B5OqUnNU`